# Requesting remote XML data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, same-origin-policy

Ok here's my problem. I'm working on this little site called 10winstreak and I'm trying to detect if a stream is live or not with javascript because our server that we run the site off of cant handle processing every single request with PHP. The basis of detecting if a stream is live or not is you go to their XML file and in one of their tags (if it's live) it will say something along the lines of true and often time the XML file on their site will be empty if a particular stream isn't live. for example if you have a twitch.tv stream for gamespot you go to http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?channel=gamespot and if it's got stuff in it then it's live if not then it's not.

so basically my code looks like this:

```
    function check (URL, term){
    $.get(URL , function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //data is whatever the server returns from the request, do whatever is needed with it to show who is live.

        var number = data.search(term);
        if (number > -1)            
        {
            document.write("Live");
        }

        else 
        {   
            document.write("Offline");
        }
    });
    }
```

and URL is a url that gets passed in and term is the term to search for in the xml file (usually "true" or "True"). but before anything happens I end up with "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=6815. Origin (my server's URL) is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

I've looked into it all over the net and i dont seem to be able to find anything that I can use. there's alot of theory stuff but not enough actual code and i dont understand the theory stuff to be able to start typing code out. from what i've seen you have 2 ways to go, use JSONP or add a line somewhere in your sever to allow for cross-domain accessing. neither of which i understand fully nor know how or what to do. It would be alot of help for someone to show me what needs to be done to get rid of this error. of course if you can explain it to a non-coder like me it would be even more awesome but at my current point, as long as the code works for all I care it might as well be magic lol.

Comment: "from what i've seen you have 2 ways to go, use JSONP or add a line somewhere in your sever" - Just to clarify, both of these things have to happen on the remote-end (ie. on justin.tv's servers, not your's).  There are things you can do on your end though (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it :)

Take a look at [xReader](http://kincrew.github.com/xReader/)

```
<script src="http://kincrew.github.com/xReader/xReader.full.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
xReader("http://api.own3d.tv/liveCheck.php?live_id=6815", function(data) { 
    alert(data.content); 
})
</script>
```

I think you need cacheburst option. but you can be banned from YQL.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: unless 10winstreak offers a JSONP service, you'll have to do things on the server-side.

Slightly longer answer:

For security reasons browsers won't let you make AJAX requests from www.example.com to www.example2.com (or any other domain except www.example.com).  There isn't much you can do about this except use JSONP (and you can only do that if the remote webservice offers it).

Therefore, what you end up needing to do is ask your server "hey what's on that other server?" and (since it's not limited the way a browser is) it can go get the XML from that other server.  There are various ways of doing this, either with code or Apache config; not sure what's right for you, but hopefully now you understand the general principle.

P.S. See this question: [Wouldn't have been simpler to just discard cookies for cross-domain XHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110764/wouldnt-have-been-simpler-to-just-discard-cookies-for-cross-domain-xhr) if you are curious *why* browsers do this.

*** EDIT ***

I just checked out JustinTV's site, and it appears that they already have a PHP library for you to use:
https://github.com/jtvapi/jtv_php_api

This is very likely your best bet (if you want to keep using PHP that is; if not they have libraries for other languages: http://www.justin.tv/p/api).

Comment: Well I got it working with php but I can't keep using php because our server is not that powerful. That's why I'm trying to do it with JS instead. Also I have root access to 10winstreak.com so I can technically play with these things.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the (client-side) problem: it's not on your (10winstreak.com's) end.  Nothing you can possibly do on 10winstreak.com (client-side) will allow you to violate the cross-domain policy.  That's just a fact of how browsers work.  This means you either need to get the remote service to "fix" things (by offering JSONP or adding your domain to their file), or (and this is probably what you need to do) you need to cut the browser out of the picture and make all requests to justin.tv from your server (probably via that PHP library I linked).

Comment: As for "can't keep using php because our server is not that powerful", acting as a proxy (which is basically what your server will be doing) shouldn't be that taxing.  However, if you are streaming video, it *could* be an issue; if that's the case you should look in to Apache proxy setups (basically you have Apache forward every request to 10winstreak.com:5555 to justin.tv, then you alias 10winstreak.com/justintv to point to 10winstreak.com:5555).  Having Apache do the proxy work should be even less taxing on your server.

Comment: Ok for the php, I was using the function file_get_contents(URL); and I will have to do that like 20+ (maybe up to 200 times) per load and also have to search the results for the term "true" in them and if we're getting too many requests, it might be a bit more taxing than I'd hope for... Unless that's not as taking as I thought it would be. Thought?

Comment: There's a golden rule of performance optimization: metric first.  Ideally you want to use the library that was designed specifically for this purpose, so I'd start by taking half an hour to whip up a "Hello world" with that library, and then another half hour invoking that hello world a thousand times so that you can really see the performance.  Most likely, you'll see that your server can handle it, and then you can convert the "hello world" in to a true implementation.

Comment: If it does have performance problems, then you'll want to convert the "hello world" to another format (maybe your own implementation with file_get_contents, maybe an Apache proxy-based implementation; whatever you think has the best chance of success).  Again, repeat that new "hello world" a thousand (or some large number) of times, and hopefully confirm the performance is adequate.

Comment: If, after trying several implementations, including an Apache proxy one, you STILL can't get decent performance ... it's time to invest in a new server ;-)  But I strongly suspect that spending those few hours getting real metrics will be far more valuable than trying to make an educated guess as to how things will perform; in my experience we programmers love making educated guesses, and normally we're pretty good at them, but when it comes to performance we're almost always wrong.

Comment: P.S. The "entirely new server" comment isn't entirely flippant; imagine how much time you're wasting on all this, and multiply that by your hourly/daily/whatever rate.  I strongly suspect it won't be long before you wasting your time trying to eke performance out of an old server is grossly more expensive than just buying a new server.  Hardware is cheap, programmers are expensive (Jeff Atwood, co-founder of this site, had a great blog post saying as much: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/12/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive.html).

Comment: as far as the performance goes, i think I've witnessed something of the sort before when we were on our old site. there was a time that the site got alot of hits and each page load was doing something like 30-40 searches via php to find out if a stream is live or not and at about 60-80 users the site crashed and no new users were able to get on the site. not entirely sure if the code that was originally implemented and what i currently have is on the same page because i'm picking up the project from someone else's design. personally i'm a media-artist my group mates are designer.

Comment: that's actually the biggest reason why i'm trying to implement something client side so we dont have to end up crashing the site during our events where we are expecting roughly 40 (smaller events) to 200 (larger multi-day events) people on our site.

Comment: Unfortunately that just isn't possible, unless: A) Justin TV offers a JSONP service, B) Justin TV adds your site to their crossdomain.xml file, C) you ask every single visitor on your site to go change a setting in their browser.  Otherwise your customers' browsers are going to try and protect them from attacks, and that means stopping your site from making AJAX requests to Justin TV (or anywhere else other than your site).

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the path is not relative. You may be calling this from a different domain/sub-domain. You can potentially allow other origins to access, which may open up a security hole or you can create a proxy locally.

In PHP creating a proxy is easy: http://blog.proxybonanza.com/programming/php-curl-with-proxy/
Now, instead of directing your request straight to that URL send the request from jQuery to your own local url and have it access it on the server side.

Another option would be to use YQL: http://www.parrisstudios.com/?p=333 (I wrote an article about this a while ago)... In that way you can turn the response into JSON, which can be accessed cross-domain (as can javascript).

You could ask for the API responses to all be returned using a JSONP server and in JSON.

Comment: "You could ask for the API responses to all be returned using JSON as well!" If his problem is the same-origin policy it doesn't matter what format the remote service uses: the problem is that it's on another domain.

Comment: @machineghost json is accessible cross-domain with a JSONP server. I will be more explicit.

Comment: :-) Thanks for updating, it's an important distinction: JSON is just a format, JSON*P* is a mode of interaction.

Comment: Think I can get some code? I can't really turn anything into contact code myself sorry :(

Comment: Point of etiquette: Stack Overflow is a place to get help, knowledge, answers to your questions, etc.  It is NOT the place to ask people to do your work for you (including asking someone to write code for you).  SO is full of cross-domain AJAX questions (any of which you could have read and saved everyone's time).  Nevertheless, both Parris and myself (and JayC to a lesser extent) took our time to help you, and we provided a great deal of info.  You can solve your problem using any of the numerous suggestions we've made; it's unfair (and arguably rude) to ask us to do it for you :-(

Comment: Reading my previous comment back, it came off a bit harsh.  Please do not take it as me chastising you; I certainly don't want to scare newcomers away!  Rather, please take it as me trying to inform you of how Stack Overflow works, and what is and isn't considered proper etiquette here.

Comment: @MuggyAte well, you have the proxy in php. You have the ajax code. You just make a request to your local php code from the jquery ajax code and send the URL you need to be proxied. The response should be the XML file. Do you need something more specific? Are you wondering about something in particular?

Comment: Ok what I'm getting is there's absolutely nothing I can do on my end to make this work. As for proxy have no idea how to set that up. I'm leaning towards getting the xml via php and leave the data handling to JS. Thanks for the help tho :) and i'm sorry for asking too much. :(

Comment: @MuggyAte if you are going to create a php proxy, just take the proxybonanza code and put it in some .php file. If you want to pass variables into the url go ahead and do so. It might be useful to specify a url variable in the url like: proxy.php?url=http://myurl ...  You can test if this works by typing the full url in browser including the url for the service you are trying to get (like justintv). Next take that full url and put it in your jquery $.get so `proxy.php?url=http://...justin.tv...` Are you getting an error? What isn't working exactly?

Comment: actually, i'm on my school network and proxybonanza's url got blocked by my school's security. i guess i'm stuck doing the other thing. :/

Comment: It got blocked because your school doesn't allow proxies lol. Access it from a different network or just search for another resource. Look for: curl php proxy or just php proxy. The YQL method is valid as well though.

Comment: Thanks. If my school doesn't allow for proxies then chances are if u implement it this way, others won't be able to view the site at school. Is that a true assumption?

Comment: @MuggyAte that should not be the case unless you create a site called proxyheaven.com or something ha. Almost every website out there has a proxy of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to do this via client-side javascript unless they've enabled *some* way to retrieve their data cross-domain ([CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing), [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), some flash widgety thing getting read permissions from [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) file(s) located on their server...)